# Impossible to access/add local network PC/drives after malware

Tags: windows-7, networking, malware, network-drive

My PC was infected by a rootkit virus along with some malwares. 
I fully cleaned it using MalwareBytes AntiMalware, Anti-Rootkit, ADWCleaner and RogueKiller, so I know it's clean.

Since the infection (yesterday) I can't access local PCs on the network. It says I don't have the authorization to do so. I can ping the computers just fine.

Also, I can access the now-clean computer from other computers.

This issue deactivated my mapped network drives and I can't reactivate them or add newer ones because if the issue mentioned above.

I've checked a few things in the local group policies, sharing and advanced sharing, security settings but couldn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you were infected by 'some' malwares and by a rootkit, it's highly recommended you format your machine and reinstall Windows. There is no guarantee you 'cleaned' your machine.

Start up your machine in Safe Mode (F8 key during boot up), and back up your data.

Reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I did a system restore to about 1 week ago and the problem was gone.
I then performed scans again. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

Well we don't know what that virus affected. It could have removed key components, or who knows what so my suggestion is probably what you don't want to hear but possibly reinstalling windows or doing a windows repair option might be a good way to go.